# Your org doesn't have access to component home:newsPanel

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, source-push

I am running a PS script with

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

to a scratch org and getting the following error:

> Your org doesn't have access to component home:newsPanel.

The scratch org is being created a few steps earlier in the same PS script (after deleting the previously-created one with the same name). So, I cannot open the scratch org to adjust any settings.

The component is the General Business News that we have on the app homepage.[image]

In my understanding, I can provide access by adjusting config in project-scratch-def.json, but I can't find the correct setting name for this particular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Enable News property in the Account Settings area.  Using the [AccountIntelligenceSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_accountintelligencesettings.htm) like:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "accountIntelligenceSettings": {
            "enableNewsStories": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: @Dmitriy glad I can help!